# Delay rendering of nested route using react router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a parent component `Messages` at `/messages` and a child component `Message` at `/messages/:id`. `Messages` fetches all messages using a promise. When I am visiting `/messages`, it renders all the messages and then clicking on a message, renders the child component.

But, when I am visiting `/messages/:id` directly, the child component mounts first and then the parent component mounts. Is there a way to render the parent component first, finish the promise execution and then render the child?

Here are the components:

**Messages**

```
class Messages extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    fetchMessages()
      .then(messages => dispatch(setMessages(messages));
  }
  render () {
    return <div>
      <Route path='/messages/:id' component={Message} />
    </div>;
  }
}
```

**Message**

```
const Message = ({
  message
}) => {
  return <div>{message}</div>;
};

function mapStateToProps (state, ownProps) {
  return {
    message: state.messages.find(msg => msg.id === ownProps.match.params.id)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Message)
```

Comment: You could have your child component be a pure function and pass it props from the parent. When the child component does not have the props it needs, have it return null. In the parent you can store the newly fetched message info in your store and should update your child component that has props mapped to that slice of state.